# NodeJS: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' when trying to create a node module package

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

Firstly, I am very to the world or Node.js etc so apologies if this is an obvious problem.

I am creating a custom packages with a few components:

One component for example is this?

```
class MailProcess {
    constructor(name, code) {
        this.name = name;
        this.code = code;
    }
}

module.exports = {MailProcess: MailProcess};
```

and in my index file:

```
export {MailProcess} from "./mail/MailProcess";
// export more components like above
```

and my json file:

```
{
  "name": "packagename",
  "version": "1.0.3",
  "description": "Private package",
  "main": "index.js",
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/...."
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1172.0",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1"
  }
}
```

and in my Main code I (after installing the above package) I implement like this:

```
let {MailProcess} = require('@myusername/mypackagename');
```

but the error get thrown of

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' relating to the index file.
```

I am wondering what I might be doing wrong. Essentially my pack contains a few different classes and I try to export them in index so the code using this package has access

Thanks for any help

Comment: I think you can do this instead : export * from "./mail/MailProcess";

Comment: I don't think node js allows/reads export components. I have encountered this error too.

Comment: @ColinHale unfortunately also doesn't work

Comment: I guess i'm not sure but this may help. Looks like you may need to add the directory to the "exports" property in the package.json. https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html See: Package entry points

Comment: Why are you mixing Commonjs `module.exports` with ESM `export` declarations? Decide on one style (preferably the modern ESM), then use it everywhere. Read https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html and https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the type property to module in the package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "blabla",
  // ...
  "type": "module",
  // ... rest
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I had this same issue, albeit with a different setup and I stumbled upon this question. At this point it may not be needed anymore, but I wanted to share what solved the problem in my case, in case it may help somebody else down the line.

My setup was basically a NodeJs (v16) project acting as a server, a frontend (not relevant to the problem) and the shared Types package.

My issue was that while everything worked fine when using `npm link`, it would not when publishing the Types package and installing it. Needless to say that the error was the same one:

```
export * from "./blocks";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

More specifically, in the top level `index.ts` of the Types package, which was "exporting everything out".

To give an idea, this was the relevant part of my `package.json` for my Types package:

```
"name": "vnotes-types",
  "version": "1.1.3",
  "description": "types for the VNotes application",
  "main": "./src/index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "tsc"
  },
```

Moreover, on `tsc` I was compiling everything to a `./lib` folder.

And the solution, basically, was:

- Changing `"main": "./src/index.ts"` to `"main": "./lib/index.js",`. Here the problem was that I would employ the non-compiled `index.ts` (`/src/index.ts`) and import everything from there.
- Adding `"types": "./lib/index.d.ts"`. Basically points out to the type declarations.
- I think this one isn't 100% necessary, but it reduces the size and clutter of the package: `"files": ["./lib"]` will only bundle the `/lib` folder, so your `/src` folder won't be included in the installation.

Hope this one helps people avoid wasting a stupid amount of time like I did to solve this issue.

Comment: That's how I have it setup, perfect description, frontend/backend, shared lib. lib works in the frontend, not the backend with express typescript. But all the items in the list are already set. Is there anything else?